# Best way to publish Processing sketches online?

Tags: html, web, github, processing

What is the best way to publish a Processing sketch online? I should like users to be able to access the sketch though a webpage. Is it possible to do this with GitHub? Is there a better platform?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What kind of files are they, how large are they?

Comment: I'm currently using the Processing 3.5.4 IDE. My .pde source code is ~9KB. This exports into a Java application ~5MB.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to familiarize yourself with the [different versions of Processing](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/which-processing).

You can use [Processing.js](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) to deploy Processing to the web, but that's no longer recommended by its developers anymore, just because it hasn't been updated in a few years and is no longer compatible with the latest versions of Processing.

If deploying to the web is a priority for you, you should look into [p5.js](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/).

Or if you need to use Processing, then you should consider [deploying as an application](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/exporting-applications) instead.

(Full disclosure: I am the author of all of these links.)

Comment: Many thanks ffor the links. I'm currently using the Processing 3.5.4 IDE. I can deploy my sketch as an application which runs at least on Linux. I'd ideally like to embed this in html. That seems difficult now however. I take it that web deployment is easier wth p5.js, but that this is a distinct language to Processing, and would require some recoding. is that right?

Comment: [Just thoroughly read the v helpful link on 'different version'. Gottit. Thanks so much!]